# Do we need a "other" reason for closing?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I am new to review. This question...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530928/use-perl-to-remove-column-from-sql-insert

...should be closed: in the comments, the asker tells us that the question isn't valid and perhaps has been discovered to not make any sense.

I would like to express that reason when I move to close, but none of the options fit.  Also, going to "off-topic" to specify a reason (where I could type something) is wrong if the question is in fact on-topic.

We should perhaps have **an "other" general reason for a "flag -> should be closed" action**, where I could type in my reasons for wanting a question closed, just like we have nested in the "off-topic" reason.

**EDIT**: After learning a bit on how things work around here, this request is just to reopen this link: [Shouldn't "off-topic" be only about... off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086) (Thanks, Josh.)

Comment: Actual close voters have this option already. Flaggers do not, so just pick the closest reason.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: iCodez, so I should go to "off topic" even if it is on-topic?

Comment: Bradley, that means my flag to close will get rejected because the reason seems wrong?

Comment: Interesting reading regarding "it's not off-topic": [Shouldn't "off topic" be only about...off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086)

Comment: Great link.  Discouraged to see that request as declined. Should I ragequit reviewing after I just started?

Comment: [Close votes review: I'm going on a strike!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208220)

Answer (score 4):

Flag as near as possible to what the intent is. Fill in the blank is a cop-out.

In this case:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: I don't see that option anywhere in "Flag--should be closed".

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Its in the off-topic section

Comment: But the question was on-topic.

Comment: Can we change this (or request a change) so that reviewers can have a better experience?  Off-topic shouldn't include things that are on-topic.

Comment: OK, I've never requested a feature before.  Where do I do that?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski RIght here (this question was one!) Post a question on Meta asking for the feature and tag it "feature-request".

Comment: OK, that's what this is already, right?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Right, but its a different request, so post a different question.

Comment: How is it different?  It is exactly what I asked for above.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski No, in this question you're asking for a new type of flag. Asking for flags to be moved out of "Off-Topic" because you believe they are "On-Topic" is a completely different request.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I meant "as near as possible to the reason". A lot of the flag options aren't perfect fits, but they are decent fits.

Comment: I didn't ask for a new type of flag.  I asked for a way to express "other" when none of the multiple choice close reasons fit.  I think I understand now: reviews and "close" votes are simply confusing and not conducive to any reason that wasn't particularly anticipated.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski In this question itself you haven't. It's what I interperetted from on of your comments on this answer: _"Off-topic shouldn't include things that are on-topic."_ Since this are still close reason and you feel that the questions that fall under them are "On-Topic" instead of "Off-topic", that would be a different request. And huge pro-tip: If you don't think any of the standard flag reasons fit the question, _do not flag the question for closure._ If it's a poorly written question, but no flags fit, then downvote but don't flag.

Comment: I don't know how much clearer I could be "I would like to express that reason when I move to close, but none of the options fit. Also, going to "off-topic" to specify a reason where I could type something is wrong if the question is in fact on-topic."

Comment: @Kendra That has been proposed quite a few times; it'd just get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: My bloody inbox.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski There is an important point there; if it *is* on-topic, and doesn't meet any of the listed criteria for closing, **it shouldn't be closed**.

Comment: @Servy I didn't bother to look, and it had already been suggested to search for a dupe first. I would've assumed that one had been asked before.

Comment: All because I used 'close' as an adjective instead of 'near'. Gaaaaah.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - really?  So even if the OP states their question isn't sensical, and I agree, it should stay open?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Sounds like the previously mentioned "Cannot be reproduced" close reason to me! The OP can always self-delete if there are no answers as well.

Comment: "Cannot be reproduced" is not one of the five "flag - close" reason choices.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski it's part of off-topic, in the vein that an unreproducible problem is off-topic for the site.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call the question in this example off-topic, would you?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski *While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one **was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.***

Comment: Yep, that doesn't fit the meaning of "off topic", but if you want to speak in stack-exchange-ese, go ahead.  I like Josh's link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski You're mistaken that the question is on-topic. From the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." If there's not enough information in the question to reproduce the OP's issue, the question is off-topic.

Comment: Again, that's a non-English definition of the term "off topic".  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086 .

Answer (score 3):

Actual close voters already have this choice:

[image: Other close vote]

Flaggers do not, so just flag with the closest reason you can find.

Comment: (1) It isn't off topic, so my flag is already wrong.  (2) That means my "flag to close" will get rejected because the reason seems wrong...right?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Not necessarily. Close voters are instructed to vote on the post as it stands, no matter what other voters/flaggers think. If no one agrees with your reason, you might not get a *helpful* flag, but I don't think you get a declined flag if its closed for another reason. Its been awhile since I was close-flagging though, hard to remember :)

Comment: Hmm, so what's the point in having reasons if they don't influence whether the item actually gets closed?  Not arguing, just trying to understand this system better.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski From a flaggers point of view, you are letting the close vote reviewers know why *you* thought it should be closed. For close voters, the most voted reason is displayed on the question as the "official" close reason.

Comment: So it sounds like there is no good way to handle this today.  Reviewers like me will be confused, and askers will be confused at the incorrect reasons they get, and we can't help it change because this feature request has negative votes.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I think the "askers" case is covered fine, if close voters are doing their job. As far as reviewers go, I don't think it needs an "Other" case when flagging. I could see moving items out of the "off-topic" area (not sure how I would vote on that), but that should be posted as a **new** feature request.

Comment: I am not sure if we need to change the "off-topic" reason, but I really just want a way to express a "close" vote with a reason that doesn't fit the five available.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski See my original guidance. If it doesn't fit any reason *at all*, then you probably **shouldn't be flagging for closure at all**. Closure is an appropriate action for a specific kind of question, the reasons help guide us in determining if a question should be closed.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Note also that you can leave your *own* comment "This question should be closed because..." along with your flag. Close voters will see this as well.

Comment: as opposed to close voters, flaggers have additional canned reason: [blatant off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873)